# Calling curl command using byte buffer in Arduino

Tags: curl, arduino, arduino-yun

I'm currently working on Arduino devices and tying to use "[process library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/YunProcessConstructor)" to call my REST API. Here's my code snippet.

```cpp
void api_send_cell(uint8_t* data)
{
    Process p;    
    p.begin("curl");
    p.addParameter("-X Post");
    p.addParameter("-H content-type: multipart/form-data");
    p.addParameter("-k " + url);
    p.addParameter("-F data=");
    p.addParameter(buf);
    p.run();
}
```

But the thing is that my data (`uin8_t buffer`) is a series of raw data which are just numbers from 0 to 255. Because the process needs string for parameter just like real command, I couldn't just put my data to `addParamter` function.

So, I think I have to convert those bytes to string representation (for example, hex string) somehow.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: do you have a Yun board? this is not the way to do network communication in Atmega of Arduino Yun. use the Bridge library.

Comment: You can improve your question by specifying the format of the string you need. Should the numbers be separated by spaces, commas, tabs, or something else?

Comment: @Juraj I'm using dragino LG01, and I thought it is ok to use process library because there are some example codes using that library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `sprintf` to convert your `uint8_t` data to a string:

```
char string_data[LENGTH]; // LENGTH = Whatever length is sufficient to hold all your data
int i=0;
int index = 0;
//NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_OF_DATA could be constant or another variable
for (i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_OF_DATA; i++)
{
   index += sprintf(&string_data[index], "%d,", data[i]);
}
p.addParameter(string_data);
```

This will convert an array like `{1,2,3,4,5}` into the string "1,2,3,4,5,".

You can change the `"%d,"` in the `sprintf` call to get another format. You may also want to remove the trailing `,` depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Well, this is good enough. What i was trying to do was sending raw image data which uses a byte for a pixel. I was wondering if there is any way to send byte array itself, because it is lot easier to handle on server side and doesn't require any parsing process.

Comment: Yeah, if you have zeros in your data you'll need to encode them somehow because HTTP is text-based and will interpret actual zero-bytes (0x00) as NULL. I'm not qualified to say what happens next, but it likely won't be what you intend.

Comment: Great, I decided to use hex because Arduino has String data type that gets byte and convert it to hex string. Thank you by the way.